# Who was the first Fantasy heroine named Alice?

Tags: history-of, fantasy-genre, alice-in-wonderland

Lewis Carroll’s Alice, From *Alice’s adventures in Wonderland*, seems to be a good candidate as the “first” Alice in a Fantasy story, but is this the case or were there other fictional heroine Alices before her?

Answer (score -4):

Lewis Carroll’s Alice is not the first such named heroine in a Fantasy story.  George MacDonald’s Alice, front *Cross Purposes* beats out Carroll’s Alice by three years, as MacDonald’s book was published in 1862, as opposed to Carroll’s, published in 1865. (For the above information on MacDonald’s *Cross Purposes*, see Marie K. Hammond’s ‘What's in a Name? Clues to Understanding MacDonald's Fairy Story *Cross Purposes*,’ available online)